# Finding the result of $\nabla$ $×$ ($k$ $×$ $r$)

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, physics, divergence-operator

I am working through the Boas mathematical methods book (Chapter 8, section 7, question 18). I am working on the vector calculus chapter.

The question is:

For $r = xi + y j + zk$,

Find: $\nabla$  $×$ ($k$ $×$ $r$)

My attempt:

Begin with expanding the triple cross product:

$(\nabla \cdot r)k$ - $(\nabla \cdot k)r$

However, now I am confused. If I take $\nabla$ = $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}i$ + $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}j$ + $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}k$, then how can I find $(\nabla \cdot k)$? The vectors are of different dimensions.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: $\nabla$ is not a “real” vector; the operators denoted by the mnemonics $\nabla\times$ and $\nabla\cdot$ don’t follow the normal rules of cross and dot products.

Comment: Thanks, so thinking through it again, and using the fact that $\nabla \cdot r$ = $\frac{\partial r_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial r_y}{\partial y} +  \frac{\partial r_z}{\partial z} $, where $r_x$ denotes the x component of $r$, and applying the same method to $\nabla \cdot k$, I get $3k - r$. However this does not seem to be correct. Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: The [cross product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Cross_product_rule) for nabla is not the same as Lagrange's formula. The latter would give $\nabla \cdot \mathbf r = 3$, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf k = 0$ ($\mathbf k$ is the vector $(0, 0, 1)$), $(\nabla \cdot \mathbf r) \mathbf k - (\nabla \cdot \mathbf k) \mathbf r = 3 \mathbf k$, which is incorrect.

Comment: It's $k\cdot\nabla$ you want in the second term, not $\nabla\cdot k$.

Comment: @J.G. If you're referring to my comment, I'm saying that formally applying Lagrange's formula gives what I wrote. Or, if you will, that it gives an indeterminate result, because $\nabla \cdot \mathbf a$ is not the same as $\mathbf a \cdot \nabla$. When you say in your first comment that those terms should be the other way around, it clearly doesn't apply to the $(\nabla \cdot \mathbf r) \mathbf k$ term. I'm just providing a link explaining the formal rules (that we in fact have $\nabla_{\mathbf r}$, which should act on $\mathbf r$, and $\nabla_{\mathbf k} = 0$).

Comment: @Maxim I was referring to the OP's comment. When I'd told them the terms should be the other way round, I was referring to an overall sign error.

Comment: (I've since deleted that comment anyway, based on double-checking the details as I wrote my own answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Let's first understand how the curl of a cross product of "normal" vectors works: $$[\nabla\times(A\times B)]_i=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(A\times B)_k=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}\partial_jA_lB_m=\left(\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}-\delta_{im}\delta_{jl}\right)\partial_j(A_lB_m)\\=\partial_j(A_iB_j)-\partial_j(A_jB_i)=(\nabla\cdot B)A_i+(B\cdot\nabla)A_i-(A\cdot\nabla)B_i-(\nabla\cdot A)B_i,$$where we sum over repeated indices. (By "normal", I mean let's not have any differential operators in $A$ or $B$.) Thus$$\nabla\times(A\times B)=(\nabla\cdot B)A+(B\cdot\nabla)A-(A\cdot\nabla)B-(\nabla\cdot A)B.$$In particular,$$\nabla\times(k\times r)=(\nabla\cdot r)k+(r\cdot\nabla)k-(k\cdot\nabla)r-(\nabla\cdot k)r=3k+0-\partial_zr-0=3k-k=2k.$$

Comment: Thanks this is an awesome explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You can just calculate it explicitly, step by step. $$ k \times r = \begin{vmatrix} i & j & k \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ x & y & z \end{vmatrix} = -yi + xj$$ then we can just directly compute the curl of the resulting vector-valued function. $$\nabla \times (k \times r) = \begin{vmatrix}i & j & k \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} 
 & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ -y & x & 0\end{vmatrix} = \boxed{2k}$$

Comment: If OP's approach is not correct, It may be more helpful for them if you could also explain why.

Comment: Thanks this is a very clear and precise explanation, but just for my own conceptual understanding, what is the issue with my current method of expanding out the dot products?

Comment: This is almost an irrelevant remark, in light of J.G.'s excellent answer, but in particular one can note that if one were to go through the derivation as J.G. did except with scalars for the component of the first vector, one could get the result you cite for normal vectors, in the sense defined by J.G. The difference, in that context, is clear. When you apply the differential operators to a product in particular, you don't just multiply you need the whole product rule, so you end up with more terms.